# Remove SVG rendered path on Legend Item Click

Tags: javascript, angular, highcharts

This is my [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/_csheth/8ak43209/7/)

I'm plotting the Arrow mark at the end of some series by rendering the path element. When I hide other legends arrow mark gets shifted, without removing rendered arrow mark.

I tried removing rendered elements using the below ways

1. by using destroy method on the arrow mark series.

```
plotOptions: {
  series: {
   events: {
     legendItemClick: {
//svgElements are retrieved from called function which draws arrow mark
     svgElements.forEach((ele) => {
                  if(ele.d !== 'M 0 0')
                    ele.destroy();
                })
   }
  }
 }
}
```

2. by using the remove method

```
svgElements.forEach((ele) => {
                  if(ele.d !== 'M 0 0')
                    ele.element.remove();
                })
```

3. by using id on SVG

```
svgElements.forEach((ele) => {
                  if(ele.d !== 'M 0 0')
                    $('#legend4').remove();
                })
```

4. by using safeRemoveChild method

```
svgElements.forEach((ele) => {
                  if(ele.d !== 'M 0 0')
                    ele.safeRemoveChild(ele.element);
                })
```

But none of them worked. Any suggestions will be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to remove the custom arrows, it is enough if you update their positions. For example:

```
if (series.customArrow) {
  series.customArrow.attr({
    d: path
  })
} else {
  series.customArrow = series.chart.renderer.path(path)
    .attr({
      fill: series.color
    })
    .add(series.group);
}
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/wv41sqro/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.SVGElement